# Is SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express the same as Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, sql-server-2008

A while back, I installed SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services, which installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (SSMS) Express as well. Now that we have SQL 2008 Standard on the network some months later, I want to confirm that I don't have to reinstall SSMS 2008 on my desktop. This blog post I found seems to suggest that I'm fine with the version of SSMS that came with SQL Express:

http://weblogs.asp.net/markwisecarver/archive/2008/09/02/sql-server-2008-management-tools-basic-vs-complete.aspx

...but I want to confirm. Unfortunately, the About dialog doesn't give details about an Express vs. a "Full" version of the tool. Anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different.  SSMS Express appears to be somewhat of a hybrid of several standard SQL 2008 applications, each paired down to some extent and packaged together. Read more [here](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/02/sql-server-2008-management-studio.html).  You can get more details on SSMSE [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx).  If I were you I would install the full set of tools from the standard addition.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are different. The Express edition of SSMS will work just fine with any higher edition of SQL Server, but it lacks some more advanced features (like the replication designers, etc.) of the higher-end editions.